# AWK - multiply two columns and add result with trailing zeros

Tags: text-processing, awk, csv

I have a csv file like this:

```
Row 1,1,4.50,
Row 2,8,0.30,
Row 3,14,0.30,
Row 4,2,2.50,
Row 5,20,0.30,
```

I want to multiply the second coulmn with the third and add the result as a fourth.

I got this simple awk command:

```
awk -F',' '{print $1 "," $2 "," $3 "," $2 * $3}' file
```

and I get:

```
Row 1,1,4.50,4.5
Row 2,8,0.30,2.4
Row 3,14,0.30,4.2
Row 4,2,2.50,5
Row 5,20,0.30,6
```

is there a way to format the output in the last coulmn like [N.NN]?

so I would get an output like this:

```
Row 1,1,4.50,4.50
Row 2,8,0.30,2.40
Row 3,14,0.30,4.20
Row 4,2,2.50,5.00
Row 5,20,0.30,6.00
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `printf` or `sprintf` for formatted output ex.

```
$ awk -F, '{printf "%s%.2f\n", $0, $2*$3}' file
Row 1,1,4.50,4.50
Row 2,8,0.30,2.40
Row 3,14,0.30,4.20
Row 4,2,2.50,5.00
Row 5,20,0.30,6.00
```

or

```
$ awk -F, '{print $0 sprintf("%.2f", $2*$3)}' file
Row 1,1,4.50,4.50
Row 2,8,0.30,2.40
Row 3,14,0.30,4.20
Row 4,2,2.50,5.00
Row 5,20,0.30,6.00
```

Comment: does `$0` stand for all the columns from input file?

Comment: @nath essentially yes - it stands for the whole record, before it has undergone field splitting